# PostgreSQL make data fall into intervals with a step of 5

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, range, intervals

I have a data from 1 to N, and what I need to do is to make it fall into intervals with a step of five. For example every item from 1 to 5 goes to interval 1, from 6 to 10 into interval 2 and so on till the end.

I made this to find the intervals, but every new number seems to have its own interval. Can anyone help?

```
select distinct Meters, (Meters/5)*5 || '-' || (Meters/5)*5+5 as Meters_range
from v_temp_schema.tmp_split_data
order by 1
```

The output:

```
     Meters  Interval 
        1    1-6     
        2    2-7     
        3    3-8     
        4    4-9     
        9    9-14
        6    6-11
        11   11-16
        8    8-13
        34   34-39
        .........
        78   78-83
        15   15-20
        81   81-86
```

The output I need:

```
     Meters  Interval 
        1    1-5     
        2    1-5     
        3    1-5     
        4    1-5     
        9    6-10
        6    6-10
        11   11-15
        8    6-10
        34   31-35
        .........
        78   76-80
        15   11-15
        81   81-85
```

Comment: Help us help you - please share some sample data, the result you're getting for it, and the result you're trying to get for it?

Comment: done, added in description:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the output you shared, it seems that the `meters / 5` division is done as floating point division, so dividing and then multiplying by 5 just returns the same value. You could `floor` the result to make it act like integer division:

```
SELECT   DISTINCT meters, FLOOR(meters/5) * 5 || '-' || FLOOR(meters/5) * 5 + 5 AS Meters_range
-- Here ------------------^-----------------------------^
FROM     v_temp_schema.tmp_split_data
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 2):

there is a chance your `meters` column is not integer, that's why integer division didn't work, you have to make sure it is an integer... this query returned a correct result for me (I have just generated a series of integers to simulate `meters` values, make sure you have `::int` part next to `meters` either in your formula or in a subquery

```
select
 meters
,(meters/5)*5+1 || '-' || (meters/5)*5+5 as interval
from (
    select generate_series (1,100,1)::int as meters
) m
```